# Linq Query relating Many to Many relationship

Tags: linq, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

i am trying to write a LINQ query but somehow it is not working, here is the query

```
var Table3Qry =
   from LoginTable in db.Logins 
   from ServerTable in LoginTable.Servers.Where(x => x.ServerID == id) 
   select new { LoginTable.passwd, LoginTable.LoginID };
```

Table Structures are

```
Login

 - Passwd
 - Userid 
 - Loginid

Server

 - Serverid
 - Servername

ServerLogins

 - Serverid
 - Loginid
```

I want to find all the `Password`s in `Login` table to a specific `ServerID` (named `id` in the query).

Comment: "it is not working" - please can you clarify this statement - do you get an error? Or are the results not what you expect, etc. Otherwise no-one can answer this.

Comment: I am not getting any error, each time it returns me undefined value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter servers by id, then select all passwords from each server logins:

```
var passwords =
     db.Servers.Where(s => s.ServerID == id)
       .SelectMany(s => s.Logins.Select(l => new { l.Passwd, l.LoginId }));
```

Query syntax:

```
var passwords = from s in db.Servers
                where s.ServerID == id
                from l in s.Logins
                select new { l.Passwd, l.LoginId };
```

If you are starting from Logins table:

```
var passwords = from l in db.Logins
                where l.Servers.Any(s => s.ServerID == id)
                select new { l.Passwd, l.LoginId };
```

Comment: May be there some problem with the code block please check the edited question.

Comment: @SalmanShaykh I rolled back your edit. You have completely changed your original code

Comment: Thanks man!! You are absolutely right here, Third Query worked for me Thanks again :)